# Ruby - how to add an array to a hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have this loop:

```
car_data = Hash.new
Car.all.each do |c|
  car_data[c.brand] = c.id
  car_data['NEW'] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

I have this snipper and trying to save all the new cars to `car_data['NEW']`, but this code keeps only one item in the hash (there should be 8).

I also tried to define that `car_data['NEW']` as an array:

```
car_data = Hash.new
car_data['NEW'] = Hash.new
Car.all.each do |c|
  car_data[c.brand] = c.id
  car_data['NEW'] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

But the result was the same - just one item.
How do I save the whole array to the hash key element?

Thank you.

Comment: Ruby convention is to use `{ }` for a new Hash, that calling `Hash.new` is only necessary when supplying defaults like `Hash.new(0)`. Less is more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`car_data['NEW']` has to be declared as `Array`.

```
car_data = Hash.new
car_data['NEW'] = []
Car.all.each do |c|
  car_data[c.brand] = c.id
  car_data['NEW'] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

You can also do it in a single step

```
car_data = { new: [] }
Car.all.each do |c|
  car_data[c.brand] = c.id
  car_data[:new] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

Frankly, it seems a little bit odd to me to use a Hash in that way. In particular, mixin different kind of information in Hash is a very bad approach inherited from other non object oriented languages.

I'd use at least two separate variables. But I don't know enough about the context to provide a meaningful example.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote, that you tried to define (initialize) `car_data['NEW']` as an array, but what you did is... initialized it as a hash.

Change:

```
car_data['NEW'] = Hash.new
```

To:

```
car_data['NEW'] = []
```

The full code would look like:

```
car_data = Hash.new
car_data['NEW'] = []
Car.all.each do |c|
  car_data[c.brand] = c.id
  car_data['NEW'] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

Comment: Better: `car_data = { 'NEW' => [ ] }`. Get it done in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

```
car_data = Car.all.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |c, memo|
  memo[c.brand] = c.id
  memo['NEW'] << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

or, simpler, let’s create it on the fly if needed:

```
car_data = Car.all.each_with_object({}) do |c, memo|
  memo[c.brand] = c.id
  (memo['NEW'] ||= []) << c.id if c.new == 1
end
```

Please also refer to comment by @tadman below, if the `NEW` key is to be existing in any case.

Comment: Probably better with `{ 'NEW' => [ ] }` than the cruft where it optionally initializes it.

Comment: @tadman This cruft contains a hint on how to deal with “maybe nil” objects. For the sophisticated initialization there is always variant 1 present.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but the difference here is in maybe not initializing the `NEW` key, which seems like a harmless thing to do by default.